# Authenticating request to access restricted SODA dataset

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, socrata, soda

I'm following the [SODA documentation about authorization](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/authentication.html) using OAuth to query a restricted datasets (that my account has access to). I have successfully received and stored an access token using my client secret. Now I'm trying to make an AJAX request with it. Here is my code:

```
var api_access_token = "OAuth " + stored_access_token;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://url/to/dataset.json",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { 
        'Authorization': api_access_token,
        'X-App-Token': my_app_token 
    }
})
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried with jQuery's "beforeSend" property with the same result. Here is what I receive:

```
{
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "You must be logged in to access this resource"
}
```

If I try this request using cURL:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    sprintf('Authorization: OAuth %s', $access_token)
);

$curl = curl_init("https://url/to/dataset.json");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$response_data = json_decode($response, TRUE);
var_dump($response_data);
```

Then I get the following (different) error:

```
"Bad OAuth token"
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT

Application callback prefix: https://example.org

1. Getting authorization code

https://example.org/dashboard
Here I have an anchor tag that looks like this:

```
<a href="https://soda.demo.socrata.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' . $app_id . '&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.org/dashboard">Authorize DOIT here.</a>
```

This gets me to the SODA page that asks to allow access

2. Getting access token

I'm redirected here:

```
https://example.org/dashboard/?code=CODE_HERE
```

And then a server side script uses curl to post a request for the access code (shown above), which I successfully receive and store as a cookie.

3. Using access token

From the same page (https://example.org/dashboard/?code=CODE_HERE) I try to request the private dataset, which fails as detailed above.

Is that the issue,  that I request the authorization code from https://example.org/dashboard and then query the data from https://example.org/dashboard?code=CODE_HERE

Comment: What domain did you issue the token against? You must OAuth against the same domain name that you use the token on. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: Edited my question with the domains and flow I'm using.

Comment: Yep, change your `/oauth/authorize` URL to reflect the domain you're trying to authenticate with, not `soda.demo.socrata.com`. Tokens are tied to the domain on which they are issued. I'll update the docs to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, assuming you're trying to do authentication on the client side in the user's browser with JavaScript, even if you get that OAuth token you won't be able to use it via CORS or JSONP. For security, we drop all authentication headers on cross-domain requests, as that's a vector for XSS attacks. More here: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/cors-and-jsonp.html

As for what's happening with your PHP libcurl requests, I'm not sure what's going on there. It looks like your authentication token is getting into the system, based on the error you're getting, but my guess is that there's something corrupted about your OAuth token, or that it was expired by the time you tried it. The tokens have about a one hour expiration window.

Edit with answer for your OAuth token error question: Change your `/oauth/authorize` URL to reflect the domain you're trying to authenticate with, not `soda.demo.socrata.com`. Tokens are tied to the domain on which they are issued. I'll update the docs to make that more clear.

Comment: Understood about client-side. For the server side code, I am making the protected resource request immediately after I get the response containing my access token, which seems to rule out expiration. That leaves corruption, anything you would suggest to troubleshoot that?